# Override method `GetSizeForItem` returns "no suitable method found to override"

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm new in Xamarin iOS development, and I've started a CollectionView tutorial including a custom cell height.

I want to change a height of the cell depending on the content of the cell (e.g., whether the cell includes a title or not).
I tried to develop my custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout class as follows.

```
public class TaskFlowLayoutDelegate : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    public TaskFlowLayoutDelegate()
    {
    }

    public override CoreGraphics.CGSize GetSizeForItem(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return new CoreGraphics.CGSize((float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width, 100)
    }
}
```

However, Xamarin IDE returns `no suitable method found to override` in the `GetSizeForItem` function above.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are using the wrong subclass or the wrong method/property:

`UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` has a `GetSizeForItem` method with the signature that you are trying to use.

`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` has a `ItemSize` *property*.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I used a wrong subclass.